# Return only one tuple of SQL query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do a query like

```
select * from chr2;
```

but only have MySQL return the first tuple (or an arbitrary) tuple instead of all of them.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html#id907989) clause:

```
SELECT * FROM chr2 LIMIT 1;
```

If you want an arbitrary row returned, you have to sort your rows by an random col like this ([MySQL docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)):

```
SELECT * FROM chr2 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

On large tables, however, you might run into performance problems with this, as there a random value has to be created for each row and the table has to be sorted according to this column.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ::

```
select * from chr2 limit 1
```